# Is there any options to check condition to fragment in bottom navigation bar using navigation graph?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

So, I have four fragments which are connected to bottom navigation view using navigation graph. I have a condition that if the user is logged in  I need to show products_fragment in 3rd position else I need to show basket_fragment in 3rd position. I know there is a way using setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener method. But, Is there any other way to achieve using navigation graph functions?

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_boutique"
    android:title="@string/boutique" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/categoryFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_categorie"
    android:title="@string/category" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/basketFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_panier"
    android:title="@string/basket" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_moi"
    android:title="@string/my_profile" />


 </menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes you can set visibility or use below code to remove that item. 
Use removeItem() function and pass menu item id in itsparameter.**

```
 bottomNavigationView.menu.removeItem(id.menu_profileFragment)
```

Hope it will work...